# partitioned matrix differentiation

Tags: matrices, derivatives, partial-derivative, matrix-calculus

I know how to differentiate a product of matrices wrt a given matrix-entry e.g., $X_{i, j}$. However, I'm not sure if I'm thinking correctly about how to do that when I have a vector i.e., just one column.

I have $\mathbf{x^{\top}Ax}$ and I want it's derivative wrt $x_{i}$. Suppose that $\mathbf{x}$ is $4 \times 1$ and that $\mathbf{A}$ is $4 \times 4$ and symmetric! What follows is correct?

$$
\frac{\partial \mathbf{x^{\top}Ax}}{\partial x_{1}} = 2\mathbf{J}^{1\cdot}\mathbf{Ax} =
2 \begin{bmatrix}
   1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
   0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
   0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
   0 & 0 & 0 & 0
  \end{bmatrix} \mathbf{Ax}.
$$

Tks in advance!

Comment: how did you compute that expression?

Comment: Why is your partial derivative a $4 \times 1$ vector?  $\frac{\partial x^TAx}{\partial x_1}$ should be a scalar

Comment: So the answer is no: your answer is not correct.

Comment: We know that $\partial \mathbf{x^{\top}Ax}/\partial \mathbf{x} = 2\mathbf{Ax}$. When we deal with $\mathbf{X}$ instead of $\mathbf{x}$ and differentiate wrt $X_{ij}$, we introduce the single-entry matrix $\mathbf{J}^{ij}$. What I did here was to 'adapt' the idea of the single-entry matrix to the context of a vector $\mathbf{x}$.
@Omnomnomnom, you're saying that since I'm differentiating in one value, my output should be a scalar, not a vector - even with the other elements of that vector being zero (as I proposed), right? What you said makes sense to me, but then I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: Okay, you know the gradient is $2Ax$, so if you multiply by the $k^{th}$ basis vector you'll get $$2e_k^TAx = e_k^T\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_k}$$ Think of $e_k$ as the single-entry vector.

Comment: I see, haha

Got it, @greg! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is simple, Greg explained clearly in the comments section.

We know that
$$
\frac{\partial \mathbf{x}^{\top}\mathbf{Ax}}{\partial \mathbf{x}} =
2\mathbf{Ax}.
$$
So, if now I want the derivative wrt $x_{k}$ I just multiply it by the $k^{\text{th}}$ basis vector. i.e.,
$$
\frac{\partial \mathbf{x}^{\top}\mathbf{Ax}}{\partial x_{k}} =
2e_{k}^{\top}\mathbf{Ax} =
e_{k}^{\top} \frac{\partial \mathbf{x}^{\top}\mathbf{Ax}}{\partial \mathbf{x}}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

I assume that $A$ is a matrix having real numbers as entries. Hence with $x^T:=(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ the term $x^TAx$ is a quadratic polynomial in $n$ variables $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ which you can differentiate w.r.t. $x_1$.

To your calculation: That equation does not hold, since $x^TAx$ is a real number for all $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ and not $4\times 1$ as in the middle and rhs.

Comment: If I have $\mathbf{x}^{\top} = [x_{1} x_{2}]$ and $\mathbf{A}$ with entries, $a, b, c, d$, $\mathbf{x}^{\top}\mathbf{Ax} = ax_{1}^{2} + (b+c)x_{1}x_{2} + dx_{2}^{2}$.
Are you saying that the derivative of this polynomial wrt $x_{1}$ is my answer? Ok, but then how I generalize it in a matrix form?

Comment: If $A$ is a $n\times n$ matrix and also $x$ is a $n\times k$ matrix with monomials as entries then you can compute the matrix product and derivate the result entrywise. 
Since the set of all $l\times k$ matrices $Mat(l,k;\mathbb{R})$ is a vector space you are able to define a notion of differentiability for maps $A: \mathbb{R}\longrightarrow Mat(l,k;\mathbb{R})$, which you would have in that case.

And yes, that was what I proposed. Just the partial differential of $ax^2_1+(b+c)x_1x_2+dx_2^2$